# How to use “considering case” while addressing Microsoft Word in Applescript

Tags: ms-word, applescript

The following Applescript code does not compile; the compiler highlights “case” and says: “Syntax Error: expected application constant or consideration but found property”. I guess `case` has a special meaning in the context of `tell application "Microsoft Word"`. How can I work around that nicely?

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set c to content of character 1 of selection as string
    considering case
        if (c is "a") then
            set content of text object of selection to "A"
        end if
    end considering
end tell
```

Comment: Try sticking the `considering` block on the outside so that it encompasses everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is try moving the `considering` block to the outside so that it encompasses everything else.

It appears that `case` is a reserved word for Microsoft Word, and so using that word in a different context while inside the `tell` block just confuses the compiler, hence the syntax error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

fireshadow52 is right ...

```
considering case
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set c to content of character 1 of selection as string
    if (c is "a") then
        set content of text object of selection to "A"
    end if
end tell
end considering
```